# Assigning Application Role to a Azure AD user sourced from another Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

`Note: Everything below is done from old Azure management portal. New portal I am not sure if it supports Roles, Azure AD etc.`

I have an application in Azure AD directory "Directory1". The application is configured (I modified its manifest) to use Roles (RoleA, RoleB) and is enabled for Multi-Tenant.

Directory1 has 2 users

UserA was created in Directory1 itself and

UserB from Directory2.

Now, I have assigned UserA to RoleA and UserB to RoleB for the application in Directory1 which is the applications origin.

When UserB will try to access the application by signing in as UserB@Directory2.onmicrosoft.com, I believe this is where the consent flow will start and ask the user if they want to provision the application in their own directory. After application is provisioned will the returned token contain Roles that was assigned to UserB in their directory2 or that the roles that were assigned to the user in directory1 ?

I noticed the roles assigned in userB directory are applied.

Answer (score 0):

I beieve the token will show the Role Claims for the user in the tenant that the access token is for.

Assuming the Role Assignment for this user is different in Directory 1 and 2, when the user signs into the app (with the tenant context of Directory 1) they will return the roles set for them in that specific directory. Similarly, if we change the Tenant Context (to Directory 2), then the claims in the token would represent the Roles for that user in that other tenant.

Let me know if I misinterpreted your question,
Thanks!
Shawn Tabrizi